# Python - Encoding items in a list

Tags: python, json

I have a script that works fine in Python2 but I can't get it to work in Python3.  I want to base64 encode each item in a list and then write it to a json file.  I know I can't use map the same way in Python3 but when I make it a list I get a different error.

```
import base64
import json

list_of_numbers = ['123456', '234567', '345678']

file = open("orig.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(file)

list = ["[{\"number\":\"" + str(s) + "\"}]" for s in list_of_numbers]   

base64_bytes = map(base64.b64encode, list)

json_object["conditions"][1]["value"] = base64_bytes

rule = open("new.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, rule, indent=2, sort_keys=True)

rule.close()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It looks like `list` is supposed to be a list of JSON strings. Why don't you use `json.dumps()`?

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: "but when I make it a list I get a different error." *what error*?? What error are you getting now? Please see [ask] and the [help]

Comment: This code doesn't make a lot of sense. base64 encoding works on *bytes*, generally, when you are working with binary data. In your `list`, you seem to be trying to *manually* construct `str` objects that are valid JSON (why would you do that? Use the `json` module for that). In any case, `base64` expects `bytes` objects, not `str` objects

Comment: @Barmar that would be totally weird though, because you would create a JSON array with JSON strings in it, those strings being valid JSON themselves... there's a lot of weirdness going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your error is related to this, but here's what I think might be the problem. When you map a function, the returned value becomes a map object. To get the results as a list again, you need to cast it back to a `list` after you map your function. In other words:

```
base64_bytes = list(map(base64.b64encode, list))
```

P.S. It's better to avoid `list` as your variable name since it's the name of the built-in function `list`.

Comment: This wouldn't work because `base64.b64encode` expects a `bytes` object, but the OP has created `str` objects. It really isn't clear what the OP intends

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I see; items inside that `list` are still Strings. You're right.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga However, this answer addresses the only difference between Python 2 and Python 3 that seems to be relevant to this script. `map()` in Python 2 returns a list, so `list(map(...))` should be equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar well, the biggest difference and the most relevant one here, is the bytes/str divide. The OP has code like this: `list = ["[{\"number\":\"" + str(s) + "\"}]" for s in list_of_numbers]`, in Python 2, `str` is equivalent to `bytes`. So it works, but in Python 3, as soon as you *use* `b64encode` it will throw a `TypeError`

Comment: When I change 
base64_bytes = map(base64.b64encode, name_of_list) to base64_bytes = list(map(base64.b64encode, name_of_list)) I get this error: 
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'